# expected dense to have shape but got array with shape

Tags: python, keras, shapes, text-classification

I am getting the following error while calling the model.predict function when running a text classification model in keras. I searched the everywhere but it isn't working for me.

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (100,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

My data has 5 classes and has a total of 15 examples only. Below is the dataset

```
             query        tags
0               hi       intro
1      how are you       wellb
2            hello       intro
3        what's up       wellb
4       how's life       wellb
5              bye          gb
6    see you later          gb
7         good bye          gb
8           thanks   gratitude
9        thank you   gratitude
10  that's helpful   gratitude
11      I am great  revertfine
12            fine  revertfine
13       I am fine  revertfine
14            good  revertfine
```

This is the code of my model

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from keras.models import Sequential
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

data = pd.read_csv('text_class.csv')
train_text = data['query']
train_labels = data['tags']

tokenize = Tokenizer(num_words=100)
tokenize.fit_on_texts(train_text)

x_data = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(train_text)

encoder = LabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(train_labels)
y_data = encoder.transform(train_labels)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x_data, y_data, batch_size=8, epochs=10)

predictions = model.predict(x_data[0])
tag_labels = encoder.classes_
predicted_tags = tag_labels[np.argmax(predictions)]
print (predicted_tags)
```

I am not able to figure out where the problem lies and how to fix it.

Comment: What is the shape of x_data?

Comment: @lordingtar 15,100

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`x_data` is 2-dimensional array with shape `(15, 100)`

```
  print(x_data.shape)
```

but `x_data[0]` is 1-dimensional array with shape `(100, )`

```
  print(x_data[0].shape)
```

and it makes problem.

Use slicing `x_data[0:1]` to get it as 2-dimensional array with shape `(1, 100)`

```
 print(x_data[0:1].shape)
```

and it will work

```
 predictions = model.predict(x_data[0:1])
```

Comment: completely unrelated question. How did you convert his text data into csv or dataframe?

Comment: @krishna I used `pandas.read_table(filename, sep="\s{2,}")` - and even `io.StringIO(text)` to create file in memory, not on disk.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... 

Answer (score 3):

Change `predictions = model.predict(x_data)` to `predictions = model.predict(x_data[0:1])`

Your input layer in your NN had 100 neurons but it seems that your input has a shape of only (1,), therefore you need change the input shape

Comment: didbt work it says Error when checking input: expected dense_19_input to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (100,)

Comment: @BhaveshLaddagiri I updated my answer. I hope it helps.