# Keras - How to predict based on one instance?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I already created a model (h5 and tfjs/model.json) to predict the pricing house. The problem is I don't know how to predict based on one instance? Usually, predict based on all test data. Already tried this, but not working...

```
model.predict(np.array([0.347669, 0.048266, 0.515875, -0.166667, 0.000000, 0.378772]))
```

Error message

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

From what I'm knowing, the instance/value should be normalized (I'm using linear regression) and convert into a numpy array. Not sure how to proceed. Got some clue here but I have no idea about it. [expected dense to have shape but got array with shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421885/expected-dense-to-have-shape-but-got-array-with-shape)

Model Summary

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 200)               1400      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 100)               20100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 50)                5050      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 25)                1275      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 26        
=================================================================
Total params: 27,851
Trainable params: 27,851
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: wrap the single instance in a list. `model.predict( [ single_instance ] )`

Comment: like this? model.predict([103.7915359, 1.564744, 2583.5, 0, 0, 4958])

Comment: It probably expects a list of lists: `model.predict([ [103.7915359, 1.564744, 2583.5, 0, 0, 4958] ])`. What result or error do you receive?

Comment: same error, ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: model.predict(np.array([103.7915359, 1.564744, 2583.5, 0, 0, 4958]))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has the expected shape

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0.347669, 0.048266, 0.515875, -0.166667, 0.000000, 0.378772]])
print(a.shape) #(6,)

b=model.predict(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: I got this, ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Did you copy what I have? The object `a` has a shape of `(6,)`. You may have a problem with your network if `dense_1_input` is the name of a tensorflow layer. To see if that is the case enter this `print(model.summary())`.

Comment: Already copied. Also, you can the model summary in updated question.

Comment: What does your model look like? What are you passing as the input to the first layer? Something like `input_shape=(784,)` (from mnist).

Comment: what do you mean by model look like? Its regression data. input shape (1115, 6)

Comment: What does this give? `print(model.predict(np.array([103.7915359, 1.564744, 2583.5, 0, 0, 4958])))`

Comment: same error message, ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: It's hard to know. Maybe `print(model.predict(np.array([[103.7915359, 1.564744, 2583.5, 0, 0, 4958]])))` or `print(model.predict([np.array([103.7915359, 1.564744, 2583.5, 0, 0, 4958])]))`

Comment: I got this [[4518.988]] but the value doesn't make sense at all. The pricing house should be more expensive than 4518.988.

Comment: That error is solved. Might need a new question from here on. Your inputs were probably normalized. It's rare to have numbers larger than 1 as inputs. (103.7, 1.5, 2583.5, and 4958 are all larger than 1. I don't know what your inputs are called, maybe `print(train[0])` or `print(X[0])`. Good luck.

Comment: Great job Mohammad Nurdin. Persistence pays off!